# Could we pass any argument into main function?

Tags: c, gcc

I've seen a program that can print itself, like below:

```
main(a){printf(a,34,a="main(a){printf(a,34,a=%c%s%c,34);}",34);}
```

My question is: why can it pass an `a` without specifying any type into the `main` function? I know that the arguments for `main` function is `void` or  `argc, argv`. So, what does the `a` mean here?

Comment: That program relies on undefined behavior.

Comment: @interjay not necessarily. Since the signature of main can be implementation defined, it can also take a single `int` as its argument. Also, in historical and K&R C, untyped arguments defaulted to int.

Comment: @H2CO3 UB is not about main's definition. `implicit int` has been removed since C99 but upon which this program relies. So this is implementation-defined only for pre-C99.

Comment: @H2CO3: The program assumes that parameters will be evaluated from right to left, which is not necessarily correct. Using the value of `a` in one parameter when it is assigned in another is undefined behavior. Another undefined behavior is implicitly casting `char*` to `int` and passing it to `printf` as the first and third parameters.

Comment: @interjay these are all correct, probably I should have written that implicit int or the seemingly non-conforming signature of main are not UB themselves.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the *implicit int* feature of C (K&R, C89). If you left out the type, `int` was assumed by the parser. IIRC it is marked *obsolete* in C99. It also allowed you to write declarations like

```
 static foo;   /* static int foo; */
```

Comment: Not in any official standard-blessed implementation-independent form. But since the first argument, usually named argc, is an int, it happens to "work as expected" on a number of implementations.

Comment: @Jens incorrect. The Standard specifies that main is either `int (*)(int, char *[])` or `int (*)(void)` **or any other implementation defined signature.** So if the actual implementation acceps `int main(int)`, that's fine and standards compilant.

Comment: @H2CO3 Thanks for the info. I've modified my comment slightly to reflect this.

Comment: @H2CO3 what do you mean by any other implementation defined signature? As far as I know, the main function only has two prototypes: int (*)(int, char *[]) or int (*)(void). Am I correct?

Comment: @injoy Your implementation may provide other forms of `main`, if properly documented. That's what the bolded part in H2CO3's quotation says.